# User Account Logging into Servers

Tags: windows

Strange issue. Bit of a novice here.

We use **Lansweeper**. Looking at an AD account, we can see which computers it last logged into. For mine, I've logged into tens of our Windows servers - when I have not physically done this.

I have changed my password, but it is still happening.

If I try and use remote desktop to log into the server with my credentials (`Domain\username`), it says `not authorised for remote login` 
However, in Task Manager, under 'Users', I can see my username in the list (albeit as **disconnected**)

As a relative newbie to AD I'm at a total loss. My account is not a domain admin.

Can anyone steer me into the right direction?

Comment: Logoff the disconnected sessions in question if you see it.Check with the domain admins for restrictions on that machine you have the error RDP'ing into. The domain admins can add your AD account to a security group with Remote Desktop access if that's what is needed.

Comment: Review the domain audit logs to determine where the logon sessions are originating from. Audit logging may need to be enabled to see these events, which for domain accounts will be logged on the DC that authenticated the logon session. You can look at the server where your account has logged on to see when the logon session was created to narrow down your search in the audit logs.

Comment: Are there any instructions available online for how to do this? Again, pretty novice with regards to AD and servers (but not Windows)